# How to Add Custom Properties to the UserRole Entity in abp framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, abp

In abp framwork how can I add a new field to identityUserRole?

I am facing the following error to add a new field to the table IdentityUserRole I will be glad if someone can guide me.

```
The type 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUserRole' 
must be convertible to 'Volo.Abp.Data.IHasExtraProperties' 
in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic method 'ObjectExtensionManager Volo.Abp.ObjectExtending.EfCoreObjectExtensionManagerExtensions.MapEfCoreProperty<TEntity,TProperty>(this ObjectExtensionManager, string, Action<EntityTypeBuilder,PropertyBuilder>)'
```

Comment: Do they add the field directly in the table or add the field in the new class in C#?https://github.com/abolfazlSadeqi/DotNetCleanArchitectureJwtWithDapper/blob/master/Src/Base/Infra/Infrastructure/Identity/ApplicationUserRole.cs

Comment: I use the structure abp framework and I want to create this field directly in the main table!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add a new field to UserRole with code logic:

```
{
    public string YourNewField { get; set; }
}
```

In OnModelCreating in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<AppUserRole>(b =>
    {
        b.Property(e => e.YourNewField).HasMaxLength(128); 
    });
}
```

You can then create a migration and update the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Open ModuleExtensionConfigurator class inside the Domain.Shared project of your solution and change the ConfigureExtraProperties method like below:

```
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
        .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
        {      
            identity.ConfigureRole(role =>
                role.AddOrUpdateProperty<string>("YourFieldName", property =>
                {
                    property.Attributes.Add(new RequiredAttribute()); // if it's Required
                    property.Attributes.Add(new StringLengthAttribute(64) { MinimumLength = 4 }); // Specify Your string length if your field type is string
                }));
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I wanted this for the user role, but this item is used for the role.

Comment: Either to add your property to the user or the role, you can not add it to user role because this class does not have extra property definition.